# DCHP Reservation on AirPort Extreme

Tags: airport

I was wondering if it's possible to have the same IP for 2 different MAC that is on the same machine. For example having the ethernet and WiFi MAC address for my MacBook for the same IP address.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Once it is set in the AirPort Utility to one MAC address, it won't allow you to assign it to another MAC address. You'll get an error.

This makes sense because you can have the Ethernet and Wi-Fi enabled at the same time.

Comment: That what I thought but I was able to do so by adding in the MAC address then setting the IP address for each MAC. I was also able to update my AirPort Extreme with out error

Comment: Huh. That seems like it shouldn't have worked. Unfortunately I can't check as I replaced my AirPort hardware when the Eero system came out. I had the older ones, maybe that was the reason for the difference? In any event, I would be very careful that you don't enable both Wi-Fi and wired Ethernet at the same time, or you might find yourself disconnected. There are some scripts out there which should help automate disabling Wi-Fi when wired Ethernet is active.

Answer (score 0):

If you would assign the same IP address for both interfaces (Ethernet & Wi-Fi) you could create a conflict resulting in not being able to make any connection at all to your device.